# Replace pandas column with sorted index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sample DF, trying to replace the list of column values with ascending sorted index:

DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(7,3)),columns=["a","b","c"])
df["d1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Mango","Mango","Apple"]
df["d2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

    a   b   c    d1      d2       date
0   2   7   9   Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   6   0   9   Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   8   0   0   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   4   4   4   Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
4   5   0   8   Mango   lemon   2002-02-01
5   6   1   6   Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
6   7   2   7   Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
```

Step 1:

```
Group the DF by "date" column, sample group on "2002-01-01"


        a   b   c    d1      d2       date
    0   2   7   9   Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
    1   6   0   9   Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
    2   8   0   0   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
    3   4   4   4   Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
```

Step 2:

In this group, replace the values of columns `["d1","d2"]` with index (not the DF index) of sorted mean values based on `c`.

For example in the above group  `mean(c, d1="Apple") = [9+0]/2 => 4.5` and 
`mean(c, d1="Mango") = [9+4]/2 => 6.5` so the `ascending sorted index` is `Apple:0` and `Mango:1`

so the value of column `d1` will be replaced like the following:

```
            a   b   c   d1       d2       date
        0   2   7   9   0      Orange   2002-01-01
        1   6   0   9   1      lemon    2002-01-01
        2   8   0   0   0      lemon    2002-01-01
        3   4   4   4   1      Orange   2002-01-01
```

Apply this for the entire `df`. I have a brute force approach of iterating through the groups and each rows, any suggestions for a more `pandas` based solution will be helpful in improving the efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `pivot_table` and `groupby.rank` to create rank. After that use `map` to assign values back

```
df1 = df.pivot_table('c', ['date','d1']).groupby(level=0).rank(method='dense')-1
df['d1'] = df[['date','d1']].agg(tuple, axis=1).map(df1.c).astype('int')

Out[255]:
   a  b  c  d1      d2        date
0  2  7  9   0  Orange  2002-01-01
1  6  0  9   1   lemon  2002-01-01
2  8  0  0   0   lemon  2002-01-01
3  4  4  4   1  Orange  2002-01-01
4  5  0  8   0   lemon  2002-02-01
5  6  1  6   0  Orange  2002-02-01
6  7  2  7   0   lemon  2002-02-01
```

Note: group `2002-02-01` has the same mean value `7` for both `Mango` and `Apple` so the rank is all `0`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for in column d1? You could apply some similar technique to d2 as well. Its not the most elegant solution though.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(7,3)),columns=["a","b","c"])
df["d1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Mango","Mango","Apple"]
df["d2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df['mean_value'] = df.groupby(['date', 'd1'])['c'].transform(lambda x: np.mean(x))
df['rank_value'] = (df.groupby(['date'])['mean_value'].rank(ascending=True, method='dense') - 1).astype(int)
df['d1'] = df['rank_value']
df.drop(labels=['rank_value', 'mean_value'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

df

```
   a  b  c  d1      d2       date
0  3  1  4   1  Orange 2002-01-01
1  9  7  5   0   lemon 2002-01-01
2  9  9  5   1   lemon 2002-01-01
3  8  1  2   0  Orange 2002-01-01
4  8  0  1   0   lemon 2002-02-01
5  1  8  3   0  Orange 2002-02-01
6  8  0  4   1   lemon 2002-02-01
```